# Performance to iterate matrix in OpenCV for android

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, android

I'm new in OpenCv4Android and I need iterate over a matrix to compute a threshold.

But a simple double for spend much time to be executed (0.29 fps). 
Like this:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRGBA = inputFrame.rgba();

    Mat mHSV = new Mat();
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRGBA, mHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2HSV, 4);

    /* Split channels and apply weight in image */
    ArrayList<Mat> mChannels = new ArrayList<Mat>(3);
    Core.split(mHSV, mChannels);
    Mat h = mChannels.get(1);
    Mat s = mChannels.get(2);

    int cols = h.cols();
    int rows = h.rows();

    Mat result = new Mat(h.size(), h.type(), new Scalar(0));

    for(int l = 0; l < rows; ++l){
        for(int c = 0 ; c < cols ; ++c){
            result.put(l,c, 1);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I read that performance of the JNI is not so better. So, Is there a way to achieve better results?

Thanks.

Comment: 1) you can use the `threshold` function to perform the threshold. 2) you can retrieve the pointer to data and work on pointers 3) you can use a look-up table (`lut` function), if the threshold is the same, 4) You can't perform better than C++, unless the call to JNI is the bottleneck. 5) you can save time reusing `result`, instead of re-creating it every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve to use JNI. I resolved to use JNI. So, as support, I used this video. https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/training-series-for-development-on-intel-based-android-devices